# How to write back the changed values to web.config?

Tags: c#, web-config

In my web.config file , I have the below section,

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="rule 1D" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(.*)$"  />
          <!--<action type="Rewrite" url="//offline.html"  />-->
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
```

Now I need to change the values of stopProcessing and write it back to the web.config. This is what I have done so far

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace WebApplication3
{
    public partial class About : Page
    {        

        protected void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var configuration = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");            
            var section = configuration.GetSection("system.webServer");
            var xdoc = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(section.SectionInformation.GetRawXml()));
            var dec = xdoc.Descendants("system.webServer");
            var stopProcessing = dec.Descendants("rules").SelectMany(i => i.Elements()).Select(s1 => s1.Attribute("stopProcessing")).Single().Value;
            stopProcessing = "false";
            configuration.Save();

        }
    }
}
```

But the change is not reflecting....

What mistake I am doing?

Complete **web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>  
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="rule 1D" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(.*)$"  />
          <!--<action type="Rewrite" url="//offline.html"  />-->
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
      </namespaces>
      <controls>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**IMPORTANT:** Changing the web.config file causes an application restart in general.

If you need flexible settings for your application, then you should consider a different approach ... like using Routes or custom HttpHandlers and read/write the data from XML file/s or DB.

Here is something that might come in handy for working with config files:

```
WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath);
// "WebConfigurationManager" is located in the "System.Web.Configuration" namespace.
```

Comment: OK..following your advice , i have done the changes and updated the answer. But the modified value is not saved. Can u please help?

Comment: If you're using the code from the example you originally provided, the reasons is that you don't actually change the content. "GetRawXml" method will return the raw section data. You need to add "section.SectionInformation.SetRawXml(modifiedXmlData)" to your code before saving.